# How to type π on the keyboard?

Tags: 8.1, keyboard

Is it possible to type a <kbd>π</kbd> on the keyboard of WP(8.1)?
I know you can copy and paste it, but that takes a lot of time.

How to do this? Are there also some other mathematics symbols (like Alpha, Beta...)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For symbols that are simply upper- or lowercase Greek letters (e.g. pi, sigma, delta) you can install the Greek keyboard layout:

[image]

Note that it's a ~16 MB download, and you may have to install a language support update that requires a phone restart. At least that was the case when I tested it.

A few other common symbols (e.g. plus-minus sign, not equal sign, square root symbol) are available in the second panel of the symbols layout. Tap the <kbd>&123</kbd> button and then the <kbd>→</kbd> button to access it. As shown below, most of the less common symbols aren't immediately visible and require a long press on some other symbol's button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if `≤` or `≥` is also available?

Comment: @AndreasFurster Yes they are! Just tap-and-hold on the `<` and `>` symbols.

Answer (score 6):

You already have an excellent answer that will help you wherever you may be typing, but I’d like to add an app-based option that might be easier if you are writing a lot of mathematical formulae.

### [Math Keyboard for WolframAlpha](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/math-keyboard-for-wolframalpha/d6a9c8a1-407f-4878-b45c-f6584292a430)

As you can tell from the name, the primary purpose of the app is to input formulae into [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), but it also has the option to copy everything to the clipboard:

[image: Screenshot of Math Keyboard for WolframAlpha app showing "copy to clipboard" function]

Even though many of these symbols and letters can be approximated with the regular keyboard, I’ve found that the layout of this app’s keyboard makes it very easy to write something quickly and copy it.

Hopefully being able to write a whole formula quickly will make up for the copying and pasting that you wanted to avoid.

Comment: +1 Nice suggestion. I definitely going to download it, but it's not the answer on my question, because i asked for the regular keyboard.

Comment: @Andreas I totally understand, just wanted to leave this as an addendum in case others have the same or similar question and have different use cases.